Keras neural network model performance changes after saving and loading
I have a neural network model that I build with Keras and TF. When I save the model with a .keras extension and then re-load it during the same session (I'm using Spyder) it works as expected. However, if I close Spyder and then go back later to re-load the model, the performance is completely different. Here is my code to build, train, and save the model:
# Ensure the same seed value is set for reproducibility
seed_value = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed_value)

#%% Neural net w/ F1 score as early stopping metric
# Custom F1 Score metric
class F1Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='f1_score', **kwargs):
        super(F1Score, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
        self.recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.precision.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
        self.recall.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

    def result(self):
        p = self.precision.result()
        r = self.recall.result()
        return 2 * ((p * r) / (p + r + tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))

    def reset_states(self):
        self.precision.reset_states()
        self.recall.reset_states()

# Hyperparameters
max_layers = 3
max_neurons = 256
patience = 10
min_learn = 1e-5
min_delta = 0.001

# Define a simple learning rate decay function
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
    if epoch < 10:
        return float(lr)
    else:
        return float(lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1).numpy())

# Setup callbacks including EarlyStopping and LearningRateScheduler
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_auc', mode='max', patience=patience, min_delta=min_delta, restore_best_weights=True)
lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

# Neural Network Model definition
def model_builder(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(X_train_smote.shape[1],)))
    num_layers = hp.Int('num_layers', 2, max_layers, default=3)

    for i in range(num_layers):
        units = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
        activation = hp.Choice('activation_' + str(i), ['relu', 'elu', 'selu', 'leaky_relu', 'swish'])
        l1_value = hp.Float('l1_' + str(i), min_value=0.00001, max_value=0.001, step=0.0001)
        l2_value = hp.Float('l2_' + str(i), min_value=0.00001, max_value=0.01, step=0.0001)
        model.add(Dense(units=units, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_value, l2=l2_value)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        dropout_rate = hp.Float('dropout_' + str(i), min_value=0.1, max_value=0.5, step=0.1)
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))

    learning_rate = hp.Float('learning_rate', min_learn, 1e-2, sampling='log')
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizer', ['adam', 'rmsprop', 'nadam']),
                  loss=FocalLoss(gamma=hp.Float('gamma', 1.0, 5.0, step=0.5)),
                  metrics=[AUC(name='auc', curve='PR'), 'accuracy', F1Score()])

    return model

# Setup Keras Tuner
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective=kt.Objective("loss", direction="min"),
                     max_epochs=20,
                     factor=2,
                     hyperband_iterations=3,
                     directory='my_dir',
                     project_name='days_icu_2405017_1941',
                     overwrite=False)

# Calculate class weights
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y_train_smote), y=y_train_smote)
class_weight_dict = {i: class_weights[i] for i in range(len(class_weights))}

# Manually adjust the weight for the minority class
minority_class_index = np.where(np.unique(y_train_smote) == 1)[0][0]  # Get the index of class '1'
class_weight_dict[minority_class_index] *= 15  # Increase weight, you can adjust this factor

tuner.search(X_train_smote, y_train_smote, epochs=8, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_scheduler], class_weight=class_weight_dict)
best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]
model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote, epochs=300, validation_split=0.2, class_weight=class_weight_dict, callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_scheduler], verbose=0)

# Save the model
model.save(`model.keras`)

and this is my code to load the model
# Ensure the same seed value is set for reproducibility
seed_value = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed_value)

# Define the custom F1Score metric with the appropriate decorator
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class F1Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='f1_score', **kwargs):
        super(F1Score, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
        self.recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.precision.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
        self.recall.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

    def result(self):
        p = self.precision.result()
        r = self.recall.result()
        return 2 * ((p * r) / (p + r + tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))

    def reset_states(self):
        self.precision.reset_states()
        self.recall.reset_states()


# Load the model with custom objects
model = load_model('model.keras', 
                    custom_objects={'F1Score': F1Score, 'FocalLoss': FocalLoss})

# with open('model_architecture.json', 'r') as json_file:
#     loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
#     model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json, custom_objects={'F1Score': F1Score, 'FocalLoss': FocalLoss})
    
# # Load weights into the model
# model.load_weights("model_weights.weights.h5")

# Compile the model (ensure to use the same loss and optimizer as before)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.00090483745),  
              loss=FocalLoss(gamma=2),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc', curve='PR'), 'accuracy', F1Score()])

I expect the model to perform similarly when I load during a given session versus when I load it during a later session. I have made sure to use a seed to account for randomness. I checked the weights of the saved model and this all looks good. I am not sure what else to do at this point.
